# Bug Identification North Carolina Help

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug up in North Carolina and it freaked me out because I found it inside. Would anyone be familiar with this type of bug?

I apologize for the bad angle, it is not a bee at all, but had a striped body, which made me curious!

[image: bug description here]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Unfortunately I think it is unlikely that this can be identified based on the poor quality of the image and the specimen. It might help if you [edit] in why you are sure this wasn't a bee. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details including the expectations for questions on this site. See also [the species-id tag info page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for suggestions about how to ask this kind of question — for example including a size estimate is very important.

Comment: If you still have the specimen, please take a better picture, e.g. a “bird’s eye view” if the insect were still alive. It’s hard to make out any distinguishing features.